# Can one document come into two buckets?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

In elastic search, I have list of documents. And each document contain field type(possible value for type is 1,2,3,4,5). Now I want to create two bucket

1. one contain document with type field value as 1 and
2. contain all the document(including type 1).

Is it possible in elastic search? If yes then how?

I search on internet but I did not find anything that is helpful.

Following is document structure:-

```
"_source": { "city": "Ahmadabad",
               "pId": "A1332605",
               "sellerType": 1,
               "seller": "Dealer",
               "makeId": 7,
               "makeName": "ABC",
               "modelId": 673,
               "type": 1
           },
"_source": { "city": "Surat",
                   "pId": "A265843",
                   "sellerType": 1,
                   "seller": "Dealer",
                   "makeId": 45,
                   "makeName": "XYZ",
                   "modelId": 520,
                   "type": 2
               }
```

Comment: I think you can. In Kibana I managed to do something similar, is Kibana ok for you, or do you need the ES request? Also some document structure would be useful if you need an accurate answer, if meta is ok then nevermind.

Comment: I need ES request(I don't use kibana)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied this request from a visualization that Kibana made, it should work just the same. I picked one of your integer fields, change it if you need something else.

```
{
  "query": {
    // your query
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "filter_for_specific": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "sellerType: 1",
              "analyze_wildcard": true
            }
          },
          "filter_for_existing": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "sellerType: *",
              "analyze_wildcard": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```